# How to recursively remove .svn metadata folders?

Tags: command-line, folder, delete

I have a Java project and it used a SVN repository, now I decide to change to GIT.

However the problem is that SVN engine that I used created in every folder of the project the `.svn` metadata directory.

I want to clean all folders of the project of this hidden folder.

Is there any terminal command to search in folder and clean it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will have to move to desire folder using `cd` command then write following command:

```
find -type d -name '.svn' -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

This will remove the all `svn` files from current and sub-directories.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing the same is:

> rm -rf `find . -type d -name .svn`

Comment: I wish Windows (I have has this same issue on that platform) had solutions that were this clean and easy :(

Comment: There may be some script in Powershell, but I don't use Windows anymore ;-)

Comment: This fails for directories with spaces in the name

Answer (score 2):

If it's still connected to svn just do `svn export` and it will copy the project with no svn metadata:)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows :

- either use UnxUtils http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ with the previous answers
- or use the search (F3) in explorer with ".svn" as the file name, it also worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have fond a solution by typing:

```
find ./ -name ".svn" | xargs rm -Rf
```

Comment: This is dangerous, when some dir can contain spaces in his name

Comment: Yes. Beware of spaces!